# Does elasticlunr support exact match

Tags: javascript, lunrjs

I couldn't find any information about exact-match search with `elascticlunr.js`. Just curious if it's supported or possible in some other way?

Using

Thanks.

Comment: I can't speak for elasticlunr, but this is possible with lunr.js.

Comment: Hi Oliver, i tried with Lunr as well and it always gave me strings matching with "Hello", "World" and "Hello World" when i searched for "Hello World". I could never get it to return exact match.

Comment: @Maverick when you say exact match, do you mean phrase match? I.e. you want to find documents that have both "Hello" and "World" and they are next to each other, e.g. no other words between "Hello" and "World".

Comment: Yes Oliver, that's exactly what I meant. However, i was able to setup a workaround using custom delimiter

Comment: @Maverick How were you able to achieve it using using custom delimiter? Can you share some examples? Also, Are you using elasticlunr with antora? can you please guide me on how to integrate elasticlunr with Antora? Can you please post it in answer.